# How to disable startup apps on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, boot

Whenever I start my Windows box, it automatically opens "Welcome Center" and "On-Screen Keyboard".

I never asked it to do this.  I don't know why it does this.  How do I turn it off?

In the old days, I could just go to the "Startup" folder and remove things, but there's nothing in there.

This is with Windows Vista Ultimate 64-bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the keyboard:

Window Key + U, then click Use this computer
without a mouse or keyboard. You can uncheck the onscreen keyboard there.

For the welcome center:

1. Click Start and choose Control Panel,
2. In Control Panel Window you will find Welcome Center icon and open her,
3. In bottom of Welcome Center window find text like this "Run at startup",
4. Uncheck that options to turn-off Welcome Center,
5. Welcome Center is now Turned off

(I found the instructions for the welcome center here: http://www.softwaretipspalace.com/MS_Windows_Vista/Tips-and-Tricks/How%20to%20turn%20off%20Welcome%20Center.html )

Comment: Nice finds!  I'll have to reboot again later to confirm, but this looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Search for, and run a program called "msconfig".  It may/may not ask you for authentication, but once you're in, there's a "Startup" in which you can uncheck certain apps to prevent them from starting up when Vista boots.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I don't see anything related to either of these items in there.

Comment: Yeah, I failed to read the entire thing -- I was basing my answer primarily off your title -- my bad there.

Comment: MSCONFIG is not a startup manager, it's a troubleshooting utility and therefore best left alone. use Autoruns instead.